# Proving equivalence between Mechanical work and Heat

Tags: thermodynamics, work

At 12:20 of [this video lecture](https://youtu.be/RrVq7Yduz2g?t=737), while proving temperature and heat relation using a paddle wheel and hanging a mass to it, professor Bob Field writes down the change in temperature as $\Delta T = \frac{Q}{C_{p}}$ that is he says that the "change in temperature" is Work done divided by the Specific heat capacity at " **constant pressure** ". I have a doubt of what **constant pressure** is he talking about? He writes it down and waves hand saying this is done at constant pressure.

Comment: He's referring to atmospheric pressure. The ideal process is conducted at 1 atm, and any deviations can be brought arbitrarily close to zero.

Answer (score 2):

From the video the experiment appears to be conducted in an open vessel at constant atmospheric pressure. In any case the specific of water, like most liquids/solids varies only slightly with pressure. It varies more with temperature, but in the case of the experiment the temperature change is so small that the specific heat can be assumed constant.

In any case, the whole purpose of the experiment was to show the equivalence of work and heat with respect to causing a temperature change in the water. In that regard the use of the equation $\Delta T=\frac{Q}{C_P}$ is misleading since in this case $Q=0$. The equation should be $\Delta U=mC\Delta T=W$ as pointed out by @Chet Miller in his comments, since it is work that changes the internal energy energy of the fluid, not heat.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think it is also worth mentioning that the heat transferred to this system Q is zero, so that the equation in the post is incorrect.  It should read $\Delta U=mC\Delta T=W$, where W is the work done on the system by the paddle and falling weight.

Comment: @ChetMiller Yes, of course. I was only focusing on the OPs issue with constant pressure. See my revised answer. Thanks